# Ruby On Rails - Best way to include CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, assets

I'm pretty new with Ruby on Rails and I'm looking for the right way to include CSS/JS libraries for a special controller and method to avoid useless requests.

Right now I use this "ugly" way :

```
- # In a layout
- # IndustryManager::index -> We want load jquery toggles
- if action_name == "index" and controller_name == "industry_manager"
  = javascript_include_tag "jquery-toggles/js/Toggles"
  = javascript_include_tag "jquery-toggles/js/wrap"
  = stylesheet_link_tag "jquery-toggles/css/toggles-full"
```

Comment: One common way to solve the *too many requests* would be to put all sources into one big file and minify that, as part of your build process. But that might not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few options that are a bit cleaner than what you're doing:

1) Have one layout for each combination of css/js that you'll need, and specify the appropriate layout in the action. This only really makes sense if you have groups of actions that will use the same css/js, otherwise you'll have one layout per action which is a mess.

2) This is almost the same as what you're doing, but a bit more reusable-- set a variable in your action such as `@include_toggles = true` and then include "jquery-toggles" only if that variable is true. You can then reuse that variable in other actions that need jquery-toggles, without having to check against the specific action and controller names.

3) If each action has its own css/js not shared with other actions, you could organize your files inside a directory that has the name of the action. Then you can include all files in that directory as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8902949/1786750, interpolating the name of the current action in the path, so that you get only the files needed for the current action. So for the index:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag Dir[Rails.root.join("public/javascripts/views/#{action_name}/*.js")].map { |s| s.sub(Rails.root.join("public/javascripts/").to_s, "") } %>
```

(That code is swiped from the answer above, I just added `#{action_name}` to illustrate the concept.)

Hope that helps. There may be even better options but the above are at least simple and relatively clean.

Comment: I hoped a magic answer, but your answer #2 and #3 do the job.