# How can I include a Javascript file from my public folder using a wildcard character?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to include a javascript file that's in my public folder in one of my views.

The filename includes a randomly generated string of characters, see "648eee49" below.

`public/react-menu/static/js/main.648eee49.js`

I've been trying to use a global directory call to return the path, but it's not working.

`<%= javascript_include_tag "#{Dir.glob("/public/react-menu/static/js/main.*.js")}" %>`

The file path is returning as `http://localhost:3000/javascripts/[].js`

Comment: With only name file and extension, without path, it should have work.

Comment: Why is there a randomly-named JS file in the first place? In any case, you’re globbing from the root path.

Comment: @DaveNewton Am being handed a react build from another development team to integrate. I'm trying to include the build JS without having to rename it each time.

Comment: Maybe they shouldn’t include the random part. In any case, you’re still globbing from the root, and glob returns an array, which won’t be what you want inside a file name string anyway.

Comment: @DaveNewton Is there a way to get the file name from the array?

Comment: `glob(…)[0]`? `glob(…).first`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to use Dir.glob, I just needed to remove the first forward slash from the search, and remove "public" from the path string.

```
<%= tag.div id: 'root' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag Dir.glob("public/react-menu/static/css/main.*.css")[0].sub("public", "") %>
<%= javascript_include_tag Dir.glob("public/react-menu/static/js/main.*.js")[0].sub("public", "") %>
```

Comment: The substition can be avoided with the base argument:

`Dir.glob("react-menu/static/js/main.*.js", base: "public").first`

Answer (score 0):

Please check this too

```
javascript_include_tag *Dir[Rails.root.join("/public/react-menu/static/js/main.*.js")]
```

[How to use javascript_include_tag to get all scripts in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714945/how-to-use-javascript-include-tag-to-get-all-scripts-in-a-folder)